# PHP anything with string

Tags: php

I'm making php script that open's directory and write something in files.
Problem is in directory.Directory name is not fixed, it changes every time in name "dir + some random number".

Is there any way to make something like this 
I need that function "anything"

```
<?php
$directory = "files/dir".anything()."/other..";
?>
```

Comment: So the problem is that you're having trouble writing files to the directory because it may not exist, correct?

Comment: ...or is the problem that you need a way to make sure the new directory name is unique? Please be more specific of you will get misguided answers. Show some more code that demonstrates your problem, if at all possible.

Comment: Ok, here's again :
I have directory with name "dir and some random number" and i need to know what is that random number to get in the directory ..

Comment: you should list directories within /files/dir/randomname/other

Comment: Ahh. So it turns out that the directory already exists and the OP needed to know what the random 'anything' bit was. I recommend a hearty dose of "ls -1" as a starting point followed by some regular expressions as a pick-me-up. If @user1366180 has actually explained what they needed in tht first place, he may have had an answer sooner

Comment: @DaveyBoy I'm still voting for closure as this question meets a lot of the guidelines: "ambiguous, vague, incomplete"... if the OP want's help, the OP must put at least minimal effort in asking the question.

Comment: Right there with you @Frankie. I think we should start giving minimal efford answers for minimal effort questions. Unfortunately, they'd probably all be "RTFM. Do some research"

Answer (score 0):

Sure... first check if the directory you want exists. If not create it.

```
<?php
    // check if dir exists, if not create it
    if(!is_dir("files/dir".anything()."/other.."))
        mkdir("files/dir".anything()."/other..");

    // ... rest of code here
    $directory = "files/dir".anything()."/other..";
?>
```

The function anything is dir + some random number. Just use php random...

```
// this function returns a random number from 0 to 100000
function random()
{
    echo rand(0, 100000);
}
```

Comment: But, how can i make function "anything" ?

Comment: You can't. There are no extensions like with c#'s this

Comment: Well... I'm lost at what you want. You're not doing a great job at pinpointing your difficulties...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you can't do

```
function anything(this $str){}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the confusion it seems you want to create a function that will create a unique file name and then apply that to the directory path, using rand() will not achieve a unique id as [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) is not so rand at times, plus every time you make a new file it lowers the chance of a new random file. With [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and with md5 it will create a 128bit alpha numerical hash from uniqid/microtime, the odds of having the same hash returned are pretty slim to none:

So you should be doing something like:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Function to create 128bit unique hash string.
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function anything(){
    return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}

/*
You should store value in a variable if you need to use it further along
or in the future.
*/
$uniq_token = anything();

$directory = "files/".$uniq_token."/other..";
?>
```

You would need to store `$uniq_token` somewhere within a database, else you will loose reference to that file/folder when trying to retrieve ect.

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something here?

WRite a function `anything` which returns a whatever you want. This is pretty basic PHP coding.

Comment: I don't know "what i want" because directory name is not fixed, it always changes..

Comment: But what are you trying to do? You want to create a random number which makes up part of a directory name? Then create a function which returns a random string (`(md5(microtime())` ?) and store that in a variable which you can then use to create, use and remove the directory. If `anything()` changes every time then you're going to have problems if you don't store the return value in a variable